# Are there any individual settings that should be checked after shrinking the model with the S key?

Tags: animation, objects, 3d-view, shaders, force-fields

After scaling the models down to a tenth of the size I was working before, the animation preview would not play. (I down the size by S key.)
When I tried to play it back, it would freeze at frame 1, and then the Blender window turns milky white and automatically close. Other than playing the animation, I still can operate other edit.

The project contains a simple cube, a UV sphere with hair particle, several plane model (Principled BSDF), wind, turbulence, some lights, and two cameras.
When I play animation, I show only the bare minimum of objects. They are the plane objects, wind and turbulence.

For now, the only thing I changed after scaled down all models at once, was to reduce the Radius of Hair Children of my fluffy UV sphere.

The view mode during animation playback is "not" camera view.

When playing the animation, I ran it in solid mode or wire edges.

The wind have added Noise Modifier.

I've tried to change Shader of plane objects from Principled BSDF to Velvet, but that doesn't help.

I've tried updating the driver, but that doesn't help.

What else should I check?
Any suggestions or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you scale in object mode? This can result in something called non-uniform scale, which can affect any number of things (depending on the object being scaled and its relations). Generally, the convention after scaling in object mode is to select the object and press Ctrl+A (apply) and select "Scale". You will likely need to re-bake any simulations and/or animations after doing this.

Comment: @Christopher Bennett As a blender newbie, I always fall into a new hole every time I take a step forward, but I appreciate the knowledge and advice you provide.
When I press Ctrl+A (apply) on an object that I have shrunk, the Hair Particle becomes long again. Should I just bake it again without fixing this long Hair Particle?

Comment: Not necessarily. I don't know what steps you took to get where you are, so I don't want to advise you (possibly badly). If you want, you can upload your .blend file (or a minimal example of it) here - https://blend-exchange.com/ - and users here can take a look and see what's going on.

Comment: @Christophe Bennett Yes, you are right, each case will have a different solution. I understand. Your advice has given me one more knowledge what I should pay attention to when I re-size the objects. Thank you very much.